# sql query for fetching result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables 
1) countrycodes:

[image]

2) cctonumbers :

[image]

ISSUE

When I execute the query as below :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   CCTONUMBERS 
       LEFT JOIN COUNTRYCODES AS CC 
              ON CCTONUMBERS.COUNTRYCODE_ID = CC.ID 
WHERE  ( CC.PARENTID = 0 
         AND NUMBER LIKE "93%" ) 
        OR ( CC.PARENTID != 0 
             AND NUMBER LIKE "7%" 
             AND CC.PARENTID IN (SELECT CC.ID 
                                 FROM   CCTONUMBERS 
                                        LEFT JOIN COUNTRYCODES AS CC 
                                               ON 
                                        CCTONUMBERS.COUNTRYCODE_ID = CC.ID 
                                 WHERE  CC.PARENTID = 0 
                                        AND NUMBER LIKE "93%") ) 
ORDER  BY CCTONUMBERS.NUMBER ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

The result I get is as below

[image]

The result that I'm looking for is when I search for 7 in dial code i should get only the dial codes( please refer to  number column  in cctonumbers)  starting with 7, but I'm getting "93" in the dial codes column as per the screenshot  as well which is not right.

Please let me know if there is an issue in the above sql query. and please refer to the tables screenshots above for the table detail

Comment: Possibly `CC.parentid=0 AND number like "93%"` this code gives you `93` in result.

Comment: Just an off-topic remark to your database design: It seems strange that you have a table called countrycodes which contains both countries and countries' mobile nets. Then you even use a recursive design with ids and parent ids - so there is something even below mobile nets? And then your cctonumbers table is designed recursively too, but it seems parants and children just mirror the links in countrycodes, rather then linking something different. Well, of course I don't know what exactly you are trying to map in your database, but you may want to look over your database design once more.

Comment: Can you please explain your exact requirement. I am unable to understand what output you want from the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have used OR with

`(CC.parentid=0 AND number like "93%" )` **or** `(CC.parentid!=0 AND number like "7%" AND...`

which suggests if there are any numbers with 93.. value than they would be fetched too with the query

**Last row of cctonumbers table satisfies this condition where parentid is 0 and number is 93.**

Comment: Do accept the answer if that helps you to solve your issue. See how does accepting answer works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I m aware that we have the issue in the query with "OR"  condition.. how we should write the query to get the desired result. let me elaborate on this issue .. we need the dial codes that start with 7 and also whose parent id has 93 . so basically if we search for 93 in the country code then all results will be displayed including 93 and if i also search for 7 in dial code ( its a AND condition here ) then we should get dial code records that starts with 7 and also country code is 93. Please refer to the above tables cctonumbers, countrycodes for clarification

Comment: send me your create query, insert query and i can try to provide a solution to your question. You can use sqlfiddle to provide your queries

Comment: Unlike ulang apparently, I fail to understand the requirements. The part after the OR gives you the mobile nets having dial codes starting with 7 and belonging to countries having dial codes starting with 93. Is that not what you are looking for? What else would you want to have in your results list?

Comment: Folks  forget about my query. its 100% wrong :) ... if u see the screen shot of front end and in that, if i search for afg , it will show me the list of all countries starting with afg ( i.e afghanistan) whose country code is 93 and dial code is also 93. ( if u refer to the tables that are there. and now after that  if i search for dial code starting with 7 , then i should not expect to see 93 in dial code in the filtered result. Let me know if there is any work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

you are explicitely asking for countries with number 93 in the first part of your where clause (the part before the OR). This is why you get Afghanistan with dial code 93.

Comment: Please check the tables as above and let me know the sql query to get the result. And u r right.. the above table design in not at the best ... but we are in middle of project so we have to go with what we have and cant change the table structure as its gonna take long time.

Comment: Please see my comment under umang's answer. I don't understand what you are expecting in your result set.